# iOS libobjc.A.dylib objc_release + 20 crash

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have several production iOS apps that all use the Fabric framework for Crashlytics and Twitter integration.  For the past few months I've been seeing a low-level crash show up in Crashlytics, but I have been unable to duplicate it.

Here is the stack trace and about all I have to go on:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000194eec174 objc_release + 20
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000194eed724 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 564
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183141074 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
3  Foundation                     0x0000000184072588 -[NSAutoreleasePool release] + 148
4  UIKit                          0x0000000187d443f4 -[UIApplication _run] + 588
5  UIKit                          0x0000000187d3ef40 UIApplicationMain + 1488
6  GT CFPlus                      0x000000010000e7ec main (main.m:16)
7  libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019557ea08 start + 4
```

At that point I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000e005bec8` message.

I've done the standard Googling of the problem and based on [posts like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429892/objc-release-exc-bad-access) it seems obvious that I'm doing something that ARC doesn't like.  I just can't figure out what that might be.  I have tried turning on NSZombies and have also run my code against an Objective-C static analysis tool with no luck on either.

My question is: has anyone run into anything similar, especially when using the Fabric framework?  If so, is this something that could be buried in the framework, or is it my own doing?

Comment: We have been grappling with the same thing and have yet to find a solution.  Sorry, no help here, just a sympathetic remark.  We're still looking into it.

Comment: maybe some code of your crashed will help. In this case I think the problem is with the ARC.

Comment: I agree it looks like an ARC issue.  I haven't followed up to see if this is still showing up since some of the newer iOS releases.  Unfortunately I don't have any code of mine that's crashing...that stack trace is the only evidence I have.